# NSTimer error at selector

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I'm trying to use an NSTimer to put an delay when accessing a method from inside another one. What I mean is that I want the method movebricksdown to be accessed a few seconds later instead of right away from my findingmatches method

But I get an error message instead on the @selector part.

I use

```
delaymovingbrickdowntimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(movebricksdown: x Y: y Direction: Dir) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

to put the delay.

I know that it will work if it says @selector(movebricksdown)  but I need the x, y and Dir values to tag along to the movebricksdown method.

what am I doing wrong when I use

```
delaymovingbrickdowntimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(movebricksdown: x Y: y Direction: Dir) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

?

ps. x, y and Dir are all integers

thanks in advance

****UPDATE**********************************************
I tried it like this...

```
//the method movebricksdown
-(void)movebricksdown: (int) x Y: (int) y Direction: (int) Dir

//The method that is called from the NSTimer statement
- (void) moveBricksDown:(NSTimer *) timer {
    NSDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo]; //warning: local declaration of 'timer' hides instance variable


    [self movebricksdown:[[dict objectForKey:@"x"] intValue] Y:[[dict objectForKey:@"y"] intValue] Direction:[dict objectForKey:@"Dir"]]; //warning: passing argument 3 of 'movebricksdown:Y:Direction:' makes integer from pointer without a cast


}

NSNumber *newX = [NSNumber numberWithInt:x];
NSNumber *newY = [NSNumber numberWithInt:y];
NSNumber *newDir = [NSNumber numberWithInt:Dir];

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:newX, @"x", newY, @"y", newDir, @"dir", nil];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(moveBricksDown:) userInfo:dict repeats:NO];
```

********UPDATE*****************************

I solved it with performselector instead.

Thanks any way for all of your help :)

Comment: `[dict objectForKey:@"Dir"]` should be `[[dict objectForKey:@"Dir"] intValue]`

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

a) You **cannot** pass an argument to a method called by an `NSTimer`.

b) Your `@selector` syntax is incorrect.

One solution would be to pass off an `NSDictionary` of arguments to the `NSTimer`'s `userInfo`:

```
- (void) moveBricksDown:(NSTimer *) timer {
   NSDictionary *dict = [timer userInfo];
   [self movebricksdown:[[dict objectForKey:@"x"] intValue] y:[[dict objectForKey:@"y"] intValue] Direction:[dict objectForKey:@"dir"]];
}

#define NUMINT(x) [NSNumber numberWithInt:x]

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:NUMINT(x), @"x", NUMINT(y), @"y", Dir, @"dir", nil];
delaymovingbrickdowntimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(moveBricksDown:) userInfo:args repeats:YES];
```

Comment: I updated the question with the way you showed me. I got 2 warnings

Comment: I fixed the first warning but I still get this warning: //warning: passing argument 3 of 'movebricksdown:Y:Direction:' makes integer from pointer without a cast on the part where I try to call the movebricksdown: x Y:y Dir: Dir method

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass x,y,Dir in your method then pass it as user info..

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:x,@"x_value",y,@"y_value",dic,@"youdic",nil];    //Like this you can set your x,y and dic value and can get in movebricksdown method
delaymovingbrickdowntimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(movebricksdown) userInfo:dic repeats:YES];
```

Comment: I got an warning when I tried this...  warning: passing argument 1 of 'dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Answer (score 0):

Pass you arguments in the userInfo object (as a dictionary or an array) and [fix the selector](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/iphone/examples/iphone-selector.html) syntax as Jacob mentioned. It should like this.

> @selector(methodName)  // no parameter
>
> @selector(methodName:) // takes the
>   userInfo object

[Apple Documentation on Selectors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocSelectors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH23-SW1)

Comment: @iphonedevonthemake Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Comment: I haven´t tried it yet... I will as soon as I get home. If it works then I'll definitely accept the answer and vote it up ;)

Comment: oops.. I missed that one. didn't see the link... I'll read it right away :)

Comment: I've read it now... still I'm stuck... tried dks1725's method... got a warning  warning: passing argument 1 of 'dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: tried Jakobs method and got an warning as well: warning: missing sentinel in function call